# Меню SHARE не работает

Tags: android-studio, меню, menu, share

Как создать работающее меню `SHARE`(поделиться)? Контекстное меню.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под `меню SHARE`?

Comment: Меню ПОДЕЛИТЬСЯ А конкретнее поделиться изображением, картинкой imageView/

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в нужной кнопке в методе `onClick`

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
final File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Для более подробной информации [почитайте](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) официальную документацию.